# Inequality between expectations

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

$W_t^4$ - 6t$W_t^3$ + $3t^2$ - is a martingale.

$\tau=\inf\{t\geq 0:W_t\notin (-a,b)\}$ , a and b>0

Prove that

$\surd(E(\tau^2)) \leq  2\surd(EW_\tau^4)$

$6\surd(E(\tau^2)) \geq  \surd(EW_\tau^4)$

My question is how to get the expectation of $\tau^2$? I don't understand, what is this

Comment: Start with Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $$E(W_\tau^2)+3E(\tau^2)=6E(\tau W_\tau^2)\leqslant6\sqrt{E(\tau^2)E(W_\tau^4)}$$ deduce that
$$(3-\sqrt6)\sqrt{E(\tau^2)}\leqslant\sqrt{E(W_\tau^4)}\leqslant(3+\sqrt6)\sqrt{E(\tau^2)}$$ and end with the numerical estimates $$3-\sqrt6>3-\sqrt{\frac{25}4}=\frac12\qquad3+\sqrt6<3+\sqrt9=6$$